Convergence of a Specific Recursive Sequence
I'm trying to prove that the following recursive sequence converges to 1:
$$x_1=0$$
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-2\frac{e^{x_n}-ex_n}{e^{x_n}-e}$$
The sequence has no fixed points, but $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{e^x-ex}{e^x-e}=0$ (and this is the only value of $x$ for which this is true). I'm pretty sure that means that if the sequence does converge, it must converge to $1$, but "I'm pretty sure" isn't much of a proof. I don't see any way to find an explicit form for the sequence (and I suspect there isn't one). The sequence isn't monotonic, since it oscillates above and below $1$. I can't find any way to satisfy Cauchy's criterion for convergence; the difference between two arbitrary terms $x_m,x_n$ ($n>m$) is $-2\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\frac{e^{x_i}-ex_i}{e^{x_i}-e}$, and I don't see any way to show that this sum is arbitrarily small unless I already know that each $x_i$ is close to $1$. I'm not sure what else I can do to prove that the sequence converges, either in general or specifically to $1$.
For some context, I'm working with a modified Newton's Method, that uses the sequence
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-p\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)},$$
where $p$ is the multiplicity of the root we're trying to find. $f(x)=e^x-ex$, which has a single root at $x=1$ with multiplicity $2$. I'm being asked to show that "the convergence of the sequence is quadratic", and I can do that if I assume the sequence converges to the root in the first place, but I don't think that's a reasonable assumption to make, and I wasn't explicitly told to assume it. We did prove that the ordinary Newton's Method converges, but only in the case where $f'$ is nonzero in a neighbourhood around the root, and I don't see any way to extend that proof to apply here. It's been years since I took a course that dealt with convergence of sequences in detail, and I don't really remember what approach to take to solve a problem like this. I would appreciate any assistance!

"... The sequence isn't monotonic, since it oscillates above and below 1 ...", This is incorrect. Except the starting value $\displaystyle,x_{0}=0$, the sequence is monotonically decreasing from $\displaystyle,x{1}=\frac{2}{e-1},$ till reaching its limit $\displaystyle,L=\lim{n\to\infty}x_{_n}=1$.

It's probably easier to focus on the sequence of numbers $y_n = x_n - 1$, which you wish to show converge (quadratically) to zero. The recursion formula  $y_{n+1}=g(y_n)$ has a removable singularity at $y=0$ so you can compute a Taylor series for $g$, which comes out to be $g(y)=y^2/6 - y^4/360 + \dots$. The error estimate for truncated Taylor series can be used to show $g(y)<y^2/6$, which then proves quadratic convergence to zero. (Admittedly, rigorously checking the bounds in the Taylor Remainder is a lot of work but plotting $g''$ clearly indicates its maximum is $1/3$, attained at $y=0$.)

With the same idea as @Dave Rusin, we have
$$g(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2 n}+B_{2 n}(1)}{(2 n)!} \,y^{2n}$$
Without any proof $g(y) < \frac {y^2}6$ but the above formula could help for the estimation of the error of the truncated series and prove it.
The second derivative
$$g''(y)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2 n}}{\Gamma (2 n-1)}\,y^{2(n-1)}=\left(\frac{y}{2} \,\coth \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)-1\right)
   \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)
   $$ is always positive and $\leq \frac 13$
